Filter using child fields to return parent with non-empty nodes
I am trying to fetch nested json structure using filters inside $expand on entities at more than one level. The Odata(OData v4.0) query looks as follows:
https://{{context-path}}/Workers?$select=WorkerId,WorkerNumber&$expand=AbsenceHeaders($select=AbsenceHeaderId,WorkerId;$expand=AbsenceDailyDetails($select=Date,AbsenceHeaderId,IsAbsentDay;$filter=IsAbsentDay eq true and (Date ge 2022-06-07 and Date le 2022-06-10)))&$filter=WorkerId eq 201&$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none

and this results in:
{
    "value": [
        {
            "WorkerId": 201,
            "WorkerNumber": "08063",
            "AbsenceHeaders": [
                **{
                    "WorkerId": 201,
                    "AbsenceHeaderId": 151252,
                    "AbsenceDailyDetails": []
                },**
                {
                    "WorkerId": 201,
                    "AbsenceHeaderId": 156585,
                    "AbsenceDailyDetails": [
                        {
                            "Date": "2022-06-07",
                            "AbsenceHeaderId": 156585,
                            "IsAbsentDay": true,
                            "AbsenceDailyDetailId": 1025375698
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I am trying to filter out all AbsenceHeader nodes where AbsenceDailyDetails is null. I only need AbsenceHeader which have values in AbsenceDailyDetails:
{
   "value":[
      {
         "WorkerId":201,
         "WorkerNumber":"08063",
         "AbsenceHeaders":[
            {
               "WorkerId":201,
               "AbsenceHeaderId":156585,
               "AbsenceDailyDetails":[
                  {
                     "Date":"2022-06-07",
                     "AbsenceHeaderId":156585,
                     "IsAbsentDay":true,
                     "AbsenceDailyDetailId":1025375698
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

I have tried to include an additional filter inside:
$expand=AbsenceHeaders($filter=AbsenceDailyDetails/IsAbsentDay eq true and (AbsenceDailyDetails/Date ge 2022-06-07 and AbsenceDailyDetails/Date le 2022-06-10))

But I am getting malformed URI error. How can I achieve this?

OData spec defines any function to test the collection:
5.1.1.13.1 any
The any operator applies a Boolean expression to each member of a collection and returns true if and only if the expression is true for any member of the collection, otherwise it returns false. This implies that the any operator always returns false for an empty collection.
The any operator can be used without an argument expression. This short form returns false if and only if the collection is empty.
ODL supports the any function no matter its a lambda form or short form.
So, you can use the any function as: $filter=AbsenceDailyDetails/Any() within the $expand:
https://{{context-path}}/Workers?$select=WorkerId,WorkerNumber&$expand=AbsenceHeaders($select=AbsenceHeaderId,WorkerId;$filter=AbsenceDailyDetails/Any();$expand=AbsenceDailyDetails($select=Date,AbsenceHeaderId,IsAbsentDay;$filter=IsAbsentDay eq true and (Date ge 2022-06-07 and Date le 2022-06-10)))&$filter=WorkerId eq 201&$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none
I create a sample here for your reference. Please file new issue in the repo if you have further questions.

Hi Sam, Thanks for your response. Actually i read about any() and all() function earlier but it was not working. I tried again (this time by removing all other filters) but it always fails with error: "The URI is malformed"
{{base_url}}/{{context-path}}/Workers?$select=WorkerId,WorkerNumber&$expand=AbsenceHeaders($select=AbsenceHeaderId,WorkerId;$filter=AbsenceDailyDetails/Any())&$filter=WorkerId eq 201

Can you share me your repro link that I can test using your project? You can send me a github repo link to saxu@microsoft.com

It is a third party API I am consuming and has OAuth authentication. Meaning I need to pass some secret which I wont be able to share. Anyway, I built a logic to remove it in my application after extracting the data. Thanks a lot for help!
